# National tragedy date shorthand (a la 9/11)

Tags: abbreviations, dates, shorthand

Has anyone coined a term for the post-2001 trend of shortening infamous events to the event's dates? For example, here in the U.S. we have 9/11 and more recently, January 6th. In the UK they have 7/7, referring to the Tube bombings. In India, they use 26/11 to refer to the 2008 Mumbai attacks.

This is not just confined to the media, as people use these date shorthands in regular conversation. Not every tragedy, even big tragedies, end up getting this shorthand, however.

Comment: I know that the 7th month is July and the 9th month is September, but what's the 26th month? :)

Comment: It’s a variety of a metonym.

Comment: @tchrist - It's the British style of date - 26th of November - which is evidently also used in India. We adopted '7/7' for the London bombings in imitation of '9/11' because it happened to be a date that was the same in both styles.

Comment: ... I can't use the 'we invented the language' argument without falling foul of the etymological fallacy. And invoking the 'most English-speakers use' argument (most are, I believe, in India) leads to all sorts of problems. I think we have to be flexible, realising that 9/11 and 26/11 use different conventions, and sticking with the local format when reading / using such 'abbreviations'.

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether tragedies of earlier centuries were first metonymed by dates and later named, e.g., Pearl Harbor Day or Guy Fawkes Day, since most calendar days have many significant events.

Comment: Just read that Japan uses "March 11" to refer to the 2011 earthquake and tsunami there

Comment: What data do you have to suggest this is a post-2001 trend? My scant knowledge of history tells me this isn't something novel to the 2000s.